# With four congruent isosceles right triangles, can I form a square? a rhombus? a rhomboid?

Tags: geometry

> If I have four isosceles right triangles congruent to each other, which of the following figures can I create?
>
> - I) Square
> - II) Rhombus
> - III) Rhomboid

I) Well, a square is always four isosceles triangle rectangles and congruent, so it fits perfectly. Then, this is it.

II) A square, is a special case of rhombus, but with more properties for which every square is a rhombus. Then, this is it.

III) The same argument of II, for the rhomboid.

> So, my answer is I), II), III)
>
> But the correct answer is I) and III).

Well, answer I) must be completely correct, but the argument I used in II and III, I thought was correct, but it is not. So,

Why the answer is I) and III)?

Comment: Because they're not thinking like mathematicians.  As you point out, you can't make (I) without making (II) at the same time.  Undoubtedly, they mean a non-square rhombus, but then they should've said so.

Comment: The rhomboid they have in mind is probably the one that has 45 and 135 degree angles, with one pair of sides $\sqrt{2}$ times the length of the other pair.

Comment: Brian, how you deduce that?

Comment: Which part?  If you mean the rhomboid part, I just visualized the figure shown in Parcly Taxel's answer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the definition of a rhombus

Some say square is a rhombus, Some say a rhombus has a four equal sides with no right angles.

If the question was from textbook, it can differ

However, I think the question was unclear. it should have said

II) Rhombus that is not square

to be clear

From what I learnt, square is a rhombus, so technically your answer is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

They are using a strict definition of the three geometric shapes: a square, even though it meets the criteria for being a rhombus, is not considered one of the latter, and similarly a rhombus is not considered a rhomboid (parallelogram not a rectangle or rhombus).

That the four triangles can form a rhomboid comes from the following arrangement: [image] If they are to form a rhombus, either the rhombus's sides are the hypotenuses of the triangles, which however would form a square, or they are twice the length of the triangles' short sides, which however does not lead to a complete rhombus.

Comment: I have realized that for any figure, with which a square can be formed within it, these 4 rectangular isosceles triangles can be formed, is this true? For example, it works with the rhomboid since it is a square with a triangle to the left and another to the right, it also works with the rectangle making two squares like those in the rhomboid.